# Get MySQL's fancy table format as stdout

Tags: mysql, stdout

When I do a SELECT in MySQL's command-line interpreter I get a sweet ASCII table:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Bob  |
|  2 | Mary |
|  3 | Jane |
|  4 | Lisa |
+----+------+
```

However, if I pipe the result somewhere (e.g., `echo "SELECT ..." | mysql`), I get a boring old tab-delimited result.

How can I get the fancy table format in stdout?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use the `-t` or `--table` switch on the `mysql` command, e.g.

```
$ echo "SELECT ..." | mysql -t | cowsay -n
 _______________
/ +----+------+ \
| | id | name | |
| +----+------+ |
| |  1 | Bob  | |
| |  2 | Mary | |
| |  3 | Jane | |
| |  4 | Lisa | |
\ +----+------+ /
 ---------------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Comment: Thanks! No idea how I missed this in the man page. +1 for cowsay, too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$ mysql -uyourUsername -pyourPassword -te 'SELECT * FROM aTable' aDatabase
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Bob  |
|  2 | Mary |
|  3 | Jane |
|  4 | Lisa |
+----+------+
```

Comment: Access denied for user 'aPaidNerd'@'10.32.60.170' ;)

Comment: how does that help in the given problem? Pipe your output into `| cat` or whatever and you'll see that there is NO table - unless you proivide `-t` or `--table`.

Comment: You're so right! What's actually sent to stdout is not exactly what you see in the console. Updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Perfect. Replaced my -1 with a +1 :-)